# Check/Uncheck mutiple checkboxes by checking/Unchecking one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi I know my question title is confusing but I will try to explain all here. Please look at my code first:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="firstCheck" onclick="myFunction();"> First<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="secondCheck" onclick="myFunction1();"> Second <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="new"> A <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="new1"> B <br>

        </body>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById("firstCheck");
  //var text = document.getElementById("text");
            if (checkBox.checked == true){
    //text.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("new").checked = true;

    } 
            else if (checkBox.checked == false){
            document.getElementById("new").checked = false;
    }
            else {
            text.style.display = "none";
    }

}

function myFunction1(){
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("secondCheck");
  //var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    //text.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("new1").checked = true;
  } 
  else if (checkBox.checked == false){
  document.getElementById("new1").checked = false;
  }
  else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
        </script>

        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check').click(function() {
        $('.check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
    </html>
```

What I am here doing is when I select/unselect checkbox First it automatically selects/unselects checkbox A and similarly when I select/unselect checkbox Second it automatically select/unselect checkbox B. I have used code so that one First or Second checkbox will be checked at one time and not the both. So when I select checkbox First it selects checkbox A and when I select checkbox Second without unchecking First then both A and B are selected. And when I again select First without unselecting Second then both A and B remains checked. This is not what I want. I want that when someone check First then A should be selected that is happen now but when some one select Second the checkbox of A should be unselected itself just as checkbox first is unselected. I want to make it like this form:
[website:] https://www.swiftcomarine.com.au/BOAT-PACKAGE-SPECIALS-X15.html

You can see on rightside of the website that when someone check standard package then some checkboxes selected automatically below it and when premium package is checked other checkboxes are selected automatically and the checkboxes that selected previously unchecked it self. That is what I want with my form. Please help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Aint your code not already doing this https://jsfiddle.net/9q3Lu8ko/ ?

Comment: No it is not doing what I want. At present it is doing this: When First selected it select A and when we select Second it select B without unselecting A. What I want is that it should unselect A when some one select Second after selecting First. Am I able to explain it clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fiddle that suits that will work based upon your requirements.

https://jsfiddle.net/y5tkphmr/2/

I have added a class to the checkbox A and B. I have added a function called resetCheckBoxes which will deselect the checkbox by invoking this method prior to your function1 and function2.

```
 <script>


  function resetCheckBoxes(){
       $(".reset").prop('checked', false);
  }
  function myFunction() {
  resetCheckBoxes();
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("firstCheck");
  //var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    //text.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("new").checked = true;

  } else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
    document.getElementById("new").checked = false;
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }

}

function myFunction1() {
resetCheckBoxes();
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("secondCheck");
  //var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    //text.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("new1").checked = true;
  } else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
    document.getElementById("new1").checked = false;
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check').click(function() {
    $('.check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});

  </script>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I want to put it in wordpress. Please tell me how can I put a custom form in wordpress.

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked in wordpress before. I could not help. @ans11

Answer (score 2):

From Carsten Løvbo Andersen js fiddle link add Line 13 and Line 29 with
these respectively:

```
document.getElementById("new1").checked = false;

document.getElementById("new").checked = false;
```

Comment: Thanks your answer worked for me too but I accept Kamal answer because he is doing it with the help of function and I have a lot of checkboxes that is why that best suite me. But thank you too for my help. I upvote your answer. I want to ask one thing from you that I want to put my form through custom coding in wordpress. How can I add form to wordpress with the help of custom coding.